# JavaScript Array Issue with data['sax']

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a confusion of what this array can hold. Also, I want to know how it assigns the values to the variable set.
Can someone give me an example of `data['sax']` please and explain me the loop below?

```
for(var x = 0; x < data['sax'].length; x++){
var set = data['sax'][x];
```

Then what does this mean ?

```
id : set.saxID,
name : set.symbol
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explaining the code

```
var set = data['sax'][x];
```

Here you are creating a variable called `set` and assigning it a value from `data['sax'][x]`.

`data['sax']` this might look like a array **`But Its Not`**, to access value of a array we use `index` but here its a string. This is another **way of accessig a property value of a object**. So `data` is a object with one of its property being `sax`. That means

```
  data = {sax: somevalue};
```

Now we have,

`data['sax'][x]` So as you know `data['sax']` is a object and then this [x] , **here x is not a string its a variable** and it holds the Number value (0,1,2,3...) , it means your `data['sax']` value is a array since we are accessing from index.

So from the above analysis your `data['sax']` will be in this format.

`Array`

```
 data = { sax : ["someValue","someValue"]}
```

So variable `set` will be

```
 var set = "someValue"; // if x = 0, as in the first loop
```

---

Now coming to the code

```
id : set.saxID,
name : set.symbol
```

`set.saxID` this is used if the `set` is an object. In Jquery to retrieve the value of a property in the object you use the `.` operator with property name (or by the property name as seen above). So the code means **set is a object with two properties** `saxID` and `symbol`. So your set object will be like

```
set = { saxID: 123, symbol = "TEST"}
```

That also means that your `data` value be

```
data = { sax : [{saxID: 123, symbol = "TEST"},{saxID: 123, symbol = "TEST"}]}
```

Let me know if I was clear

Comment: As you can see in the for-loop, `x` is not a string.

Comment: @Reddy Thanks for the informative explanation bro :)

Comment: @Badshah01 no problem Let me know if my answer helps you understand your code better?

Comment: @Reddy So, the loop iterates through the array and assigns the property value at that index to the variable temp ?

Comment: not the property value... It assigns the entire `Object` at that index to `set`. and then you are using set to read each property..

Comment: `data['sax']` will give you an array. and `data['sax'].length` will give you the total count.. so from my above example the for loop will be like `for(var x = 0; x < 2; x++){` so it loops for two times..

Comment: Can you please tell me about this ? `sax.push({data:{ id : set.ID, name : set.symbol, tax_ID: tax`

Comment: as you know that sax is an array. And in Jquery to add a element into an array we use `push`. So your code is actually adding a new object into the array.

Comment: Adding new objects with theirs attributes in the array ?

Comment: Put it this way..Adding new objects with its `properties` and `values` into the array.

Comment: Thanks brother Reddy. I get confused with the words. Lol

Comment: hahaha :) words change the meaning. Also to remind you. If either mine or @Matthijs solution helped you Please mark the respected one as answer. Both of us have put quite some effort in explaining you :) in spite of the community not entertaining the question you posted.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is an array that is being looped through. `data['sax']` will be something along the lines of the following:

```
var data = {
    sax: [
        {
            saxID: 1,
            symbol: 1
        },
        {
            saxID: 2,
            symbol: 2
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see in the example above, `sax` is an array which contains multiple objects. What happens when you loop over it, is that it accesses one of the objects inside the array. So `data['sax'][0]` will give you the object with `saxID: 1`.

Using the variable `set` to temporarily store the data in; you can access the data of `data['sax'][0]` as `set`. So `data['sax'][0].saxID` becomes `set.saxID`. It is somewhat of a shorthand version of accessing the data.

What happens with `id: set.saxID`, is that the values get assigned to a new object. Which will be something like the following.

```
var newSax = {
    id: set.saxID
}
```

You are basically transferring data from one object to another.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Matthijis. If an sax is an array, what is data ?

Comment: @Badshah01 `data` is an object which can contain anything really, in this case it contains the `array sax`.

Comment: Hmm I see.. Can you please elaborate on the `var set = data['sax'][x];` please ?

Comment: This is where you assign an object in array sax to variable set. The `x` changes because you're in a for-loop, so x will change from 0 to 1 to 2 and so on.

Comment: So, when x is 0, it assigns saxID: 1, symbol: 1 to temp., and so on ?

Comment: Correct! And when x is 1, it uses saxID: 2 and symbol: 2.

Comment: Thans Mattijis. So, saxID and symbol are the property values ?

Comment: `saxID` and `symbol` are properties of `sax-objects`

Comment: @Matthijis What is this doing ? `id: set.saxID` ?

Comment: It assigns the value of set.saxID to id.

Comment: So id is the new object ? Thanks

Comment: Can you please tell me about this ?
`sax.push({data:{ 
     id    : set.ID, 
     name  : set.symbol,
     tax_ID: tax`

Comment: This is basic javascript. Please take a look at something like this: http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html